# NodeJS Error : Schema hasn't been registered for model “...”

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I'm working on a nodeJS project, but when I moved a file model to another folder I got this error :

```
throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "...".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

I did not change anything, just moved the model from a folder to another.

Can anyone help, please,

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need to update the path to your model, mongoose wrap it for you. Just use `var myModel = mongoose.model('Foo')`

Comment: @dbyba can you give some code example, hard to help you without seeing the implementation. should be fine as long as you're using the same name.

Comment: thank's 'meriadec', well I did not change the path, I just moved the model from a folder to another, I din not have this probleme before moving the model file

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoose.model('modelName')` will only work once the model has been registered.

Registering the model simply means your model.js (code containing the model) has been evaluated.

You are getting the error as you have not "required" your model. If you are using eg a version of MEAN it knows to automatically require the all the models from the models folder. (via a script)

If you move it out of that folder you would probably need to require it manually.

eg `require('pathToYourModel')`; and afterwards you can use mongoose.model('modelName');